# How to concate laravel old helper input value with javascript var

Tags: javascript, laravel, append

I'm new with laravel and I have a code that I load it by clicking on a buttom using append() method. But i'm not able to concate `arma_number_form_index` into `value="{{old('st_arma')`[+arma_number_form_index+] `}}`":

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var arma_number_form_index=0;

    $("#add_armas").click(function(){

        inputs_armas =  '<div class="columns armas" id="remover_arma_'+arma_number_form_index+'">'+

                  '<div class="column is-one-quarter">'+

                        '<input class="input" type="input" name="st_arma['+arma_number_form_index+']" id="st_arma" value="{{old('st_arma')['+arma_number_form_index+']}}">'+

                  '</div>';

        $('#arma_number_form').append(inputs_armas);

    });

});
```

I can concate that js var as id and name attibutes but not into laravel old helper. is that possible? if so, how do I achieve that? thank you!

Comment: Try using template literal - ` <input class="input"
  type = "input"
  name = "st_arma[${arma_number_form_index}]"  
  id = "st_arma"
  value = "{{old('st_arma') [${arma_number_form_index}] }} />"
`

Comment: did not work @random

Comment: you are almost there you just need to concat it with php conact oparator ```.``` ```value="{{old('st_arma','defaultValueIf_st_aram_notexists') . "['+arma_number_form_index+']" }}">```

Comment: thanks but did not work.I get Array to string convertion ErrorException

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to use js and I solved my day using php.

```
@php 
 $armas = old('st_arma'); 
@endphp
    @if(!empty($armas) && count($armas) > 0)

        @foreach($armas as $key => $arma)
              <div class="columns armas" id="remover_arma_{{$key}}">
                  <label class="div1 label" for="st_tipo">Arma:</label>
                  <input type="input" name="st_arma[]" id="st_arma" value="{{$arma}}">
              </div>
       @endforeach
    @endif
```

so that code will be loaded if my old('input') is present after my aplication redirects back. it solved my situation. thanks!